# Query with compare predicate in CloudKit

Tags: ios, nspredicate, cloudkit, ckquery

I have some CKRecords in Cloudkit, the records has two property of int type, which may be called 'cost' and 'price',  I want to query records whose 'cost' > 'price', but the application crashed when I write a query like this:

```
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:@"MyRecordType" predicate:
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cost > price"]];
```

this is the crash info given by Xcode:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'Invalid predicate, Invalid right expression,  is not a function expression

Please Help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Ray, I would suggest this as an answer; but I not sure it will work
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"cost.@min.doubleValue < price" AND product == X]

Comment: @user3069232 thank you for your help, I did tried, unfortunately still the same error: price is not a function expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,

Thought some more about this.

You query all records, but select only two fields; the cost and the price.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Whatever", predicate: predicate)
let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
operation.desiredKeys = ["cost","price"]
```

Then you do your query [which should be quicker], sort out the records you want and then go get them with publicDB.fetchRecordWithID.

Yes, I know more than one query, in fact it looks like a lot more, but wait I think there is an answers in WWDC 2015 Tips & Tricks in Cloudkit; Watch the session and you might find something in there too. Here the code to fetch a record, if you have the record ID.

```
publicDB.fetchRecordWithID(), completionHandler: {record, error in
if error != nil {
    println("there was an error \(error)")
} else {
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
        self.plasticOne.text = (record.objectForKey("subCategory") as String)
    }
```

}
   })

Sorry I cannot give you more than that without writing the code myself, and if I do that than you end up using my answer, and I sure you're answer is going to be better :)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Your solution will work if there is limited records in CloudKit, I would like to perform the compare operation in CloudKit and return the desired records when I have thousands of records in the cloud.

Comment: Ray, this sounds like a challenge. Where does the data come from? Can you flag the data as you upload the it? create an additional field within your scheme to indicate its a record of interest?

Comment: wonderful, this is the answer I'm looking for, I can add a flag to indicate the compare result when I'm updating the 'cost' or 'price' , thank you very much!  @user3069232